# How viable is Taric as a Support in higher level of play in comparison to, say, Soraka?

Tags: league-of-legends

My main support pick is Taric, and while I have not had much trouble with him so far, I wonder how good of a pick he is in high level play.

It is not common to see Taric picked in pro-level games, most of the pro supports seem to go for Soraka, Janna or Sona instead.

As such, what is the advantage those champions have over Taric?

Comment: Fashion sense, fabulous taste, no other support is so truly, truly, truly outrageous.

Answer (score 5):

It's just that Taric does nothing special. If you want to play aggressive (utilize the stun) you can go for Leona or Alistar or even Blitzcrank. If you want to utilize the Armor and the Heal, go for Soraka or Janna. If you want to utilize a mix of these things... get Sona!

For everything that Taric does, there is someone who does it better. Still, if you like the champion, you can play him for sure and you will have a lot of success with him. While you could still see some people using Taric a few patches ago, I fairly doubt you will see this as frequently after Sona got buffed again.

Comment: This is mostly correct though a big reason why he is not played competitively is his poor mana efficiency with his stun costing 95 mana and his heal 80-140 with just a low regeneration. His passive doesn't find much use since as support he doesn't auto attack a lot.

Comment: Exactly. As I said, he just has nothing that makes him a better support than Sona for example. Sona has a heal, a Speedbuff, a deffense Buff, has Burst dmg, and Aoe stun... bascily everything Taric has, and some abilitys more.

Answer (score 1):

Like someone before mentioned Taric support is viable in higher levels of plays with burst AD champions like Corki, Graves or Ezreal.

This is not only due to the fact that you can stun the enemy, allowing all the burst from your AD to land easily and mostly uncontested, but you also have the ability to shred their armor, allowing more damage to come out from your carry's burst and adding some damage yourself to said burst.

This is a great combo with Corki's armor shred from his Gatling Gun.

Answer (score 1):

The meta changed significantly after this question was asked.

For the season 4 meta:

- You do not want a support that heals.
- Support that buffs generally not preferred.

You want a support with:

1. A lot of CC.
2. High base spell damage.
3. Early game harassing potential.

Lets see what Taric has:
 - No range harass.
 - Long cooldown, high mana heal to himself and ally.
 - Armor buff to himself and allies.
 - Long cd stun, with insignificant damage. 
 - Not bad one time burst with really high cooldown.
 - Damage buff to allies.

- Tarc doesn't have any of the stuff we are looking for in a support. So he isn't a viable support.
- Soraka has nothing at all. At least Taric has meh cc and meh damage.
- Sona has: 1,2,3.
- Janna has:1,3

So if we compare these,
Sona>Janna>Taric>Soraka

http://www.lolking.net/champions/
Sort by popularity to see which supports are most played.
Sort by winrate to see which support are most viable. The winrate backsup this statement.

Comment: What?  You don't want a support that heals or buffs?... Why then does so many ppl play sona?...

Comment: Because of her high base spell damage, early game harrassing potential, slow, reduce damage, stun. not because of her heal and buffs

Comment: It's good to have an update on the meta, but could you add how this applies to the question (i.e. specifically how this affects Taric and his position relative to other support heroes)? Are the assumptions made in the question (that Taric isn't picked much relative to Soraka, Janna, or Sona) still valid?

Comment: But people don't play Sona really - take a look at support playrates on something like Lolking.  Support in season 4 is absolutely dominated by Leona/Thresh/Annie in terms of playrates.  After that comes Blitz, then Lulu.  Sona isn't played at a very high rate at all.  This absolutely backs up the "you don't necessarily want heals" idea.  Its all about the CC and early power right now.

Comment: well op wanted a comparison between those champions, thats why i put sona.

Comment: I fail to see where I said anything about just sitting there and buffing as sona.  It's her kit as a whole that ppl play her for.  If she only poked... there are more viable options for that.  Her buffs/heals are just as valuable as her poke.

Answer (score 0):

I personally love taric for his versatility, but mostly he's a pick for bursty ADs like Ez, Corki or Graves. Unlike Leona or Blitz, if things go wrong, Taric is still a good support for a passive lane.

Janna and Sona have ultimates that can turn the tide of a teamfight, Soraka has burst heal. As Taric you... you are just there. It's definetely tier 1 suport in lane, but in teamfights he does less than other supports. This isn't to say that Taric is useless, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think Taric is a good support only in early game because of that stun.  I personally like playing as vayne with taric to get a double stun and do lots of damage but it is true in teamfights he doesn't do much

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to play Taric because of its versatility. Traic is still consider to be a good support because of his passive and his stun. His skills allow him to sustain with WQ.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of people here are answering based on opinion as far as i can see.  (Some have some good comparisons and explain things)  But if you strictly want to know viability, I'd say some number crunching is the way to determine best.  I use lolking.net charts.  You can choose a chart by 'Highest Win Rate' and 'Lowest Win Rate' (cant remember the exact terminology).  From here you can then filter by the tier you want.  It will give you a short chart of the highest/lowest win rates in tier (you can select diamond if you want high level) and if that isn't even you can also choose to expand the chart more.  If he doesn't appear on any chart or he is in the higher win rate chart, then he is either on par or better.  If he's on the lower win rate chart... then I'd say it's safe to assume he's really not that viable since he's continually losing for players.

You can follow this same process for about any champion.

He seems more of a jack of all trades champion.  He does things several other champions do, just not as well.
He has a good single target stun.  Other champions have more stuns (Leona) and others can stun multiple targets (annie, sona, alistar).
He has a decent heal.  Soraka has a stronger single target heal and an amazing team heal.  Sona has a constant heal she can spam which is good in lane.  Alistar has a slight heal.
He has decent burst in lane.  Stun + shatter.  Leona has good burst with her abils.  So does annie/zyra.
He's tanky, but leona and alistar naturally are even more tanky.

His strength is that he is a very versatile champion.  His weakness is that everything he does, someone else does better.

Answer (score -2):

His heal is outstanding so you should get 30%-40% cdr and mana regen first. After mid-game, you can stay in lane until the game is over. His burst is strong enough to destroy a carry alone.

He is useful if you know what to do with him, but he is somewhat weak in the early game. This early weakness is why you don't see him too much. Everyone nowadays wants those fast wins. Success in League comes with patience though and Taric shines if you give him some time.